# How to rank items that match keywords by similarity

Tags: sql, search, keyword

I have a table of items linked to a table of keywords. 
I want to list all items that share keywords and I want to rank the results so that items that are most similar appear highest.
So, I figure items that match all keywords will come highest with items that match only one keyword appearing lower in the list.

Where items match the same number of keywords I want to then rank the results by the frequency of a keyword, so that items that share an unusual keyword will appear higher than items that share a keyword that appears frequently.

Currently my schema is like this (but this could be changed if necessary):

```
Item    ItemKeywords    Keywords
____    ____________    ________
ID       ItemID          ID
Item    KeywordID       Word
```

I'm struggling to even start with the sql to get the items that match most keywords. Can anyone help?
I'm using Sql Server 2005

**EDIT - (added for completeness)**

Using Beth's SQL as a pointer I've come up with the following, which I think is working as I want, just got to do a little more testing:

```
   SELECT IK1.ItemID, 
      IK2.ItemID, 
      COUNT(IK2.KeywordID) AS KeywordCount, 
      MIN(WordFrequency) AS WordFrequency
    FROM ItemKeywords IK1
    INNER JOIN ItemKeywords IK2 
        ON IK1.KeywordID = IK2.KeywordID --Keywords match
        AND IK1.ItemID < IK2.ItemID --Eliminate pairs (Bill & Ted but not Ted and Bill or Bill and Bill)
    INNER JOIN (SELECT KeywordID, COUNT(*) WordFrequency 
                FROM dbo.ItemKeywords 
                GROUP BY KeywordID) AS KF 
        ON KF.KeywordID = IK2.KeywordID --Join to sub-query to get frequency of word
    GROUP BY IK1.ItemID, IK2.ItemID
    ORDER BY COUNT(IK2.KeywordID) DESC, MIN(WordFrequency) ASC  --Order by most matching keywords then by  most unusual word
```

I've altered the syntax slightly to avoid the sub-query (doing everything on the join), I've changed `IK1.ItemID <> IK2.ItemID` to `IK1.ItemID < IK2.ItemID` to eliminate pairs, and I've added the second order by item to take into account the frequency that a word is used too. But essentially Beth answered the question so I will mark it as the answer (many thanks)

Comment: can you add an example of what you want?  give us 3 items, keywords, and enough itemkeywords to demonstrate the results you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select keywordID, count(itemID) as cnt_item
from itemKeywords
group by keywordID
order by count(itemID) desc
```

OK, understanding better what you don't want, try joining 2 instances of the itemKeyword table on the keywordID field where the itemID doesn't match:

```
select ik.itemID, ik1.itemID as itemID1, ik.keywordID
from itemkeyword ik inner join itemkeyword ik1 on ik.keywordID = ik1.keywordID
where ik.itemID <> ik1.itemID
```

then, with that set, count the number of keywordIDs and return the list in descending order:

```
select itemID, itemID1, count(keywordID) as count_kwd
from 
(    select ik.itemID, ik1.itemID as itemID1, ik.keywordID
    from itemkeyword ik inner join itemkeyword ik1 on ik.keywordID = ik1.keywordID
    where ik.itemID <> ik1.itemID
) t
group by itemID, itemID1
order by count(keywordID) desc
```

Comment: Thanks Beth, but this lists the keyword ids with the ones linked to the most items at the top. I want the items, with the ones most similar to other items at the top.

Comment: PS you forgot to put in "GROUP BY KeywordID"